# What's the correct way to call method?

Tags: python, methods

Could someone please explain why the code below throws an error? I know how to make it work - in the last line of code `bob.mainloop()` has to be replaced with `turtle.mainloop()` and this is what confuses me. Why does it throw an error `Turtle` object has no attribute `mainloop` but when I replace bob with turtle it's ok?

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()

bob.forward(100)

bob.mainloop()
```

Comment: `turtle` is the python package. `bob` is an instance of the `Turtle` class. They are all different things - there is no reason to expect that the `Turtle` class has an instance method called `mainloop` just because the package does.

Comment: You're right, I looked into turtle.py and this all makes sense now. I just assumed that whatever is there can be used on my instance but that's not the case. Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems that `mainloop` is a function of the *module* `turtle.bob` is an *object of type*`turtle.Turtle`, which is not the same.